# Me dejo de funcionar css

Tags: html, css3

Estaba intentando hacer una cosa con una imagen en css y de repente cuando escribía código me dejo de funcionar

Este es el head donde conecte el css:

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>GamerSpot</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./Img/GameSpot FaviCon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>
```

Aquí donde escribo el código de html donde subo la img

```html
<img src="./Img/GameSpot logo.png" class="home-img">
```

Aquí donde escribo el código en css y me deja de funcionar

```css
.home-img{
    float: right;
    bottom: 40px;
    width: 170px;
    margin-left: 900%;
}
```

Me di cuenta que el css no funcionaba simplemente borre todo el código sobre css guarde reinicie el live server y seguía igual

Comment: En el ultimo link, estas reemplazando el stylesheet...

Comment: Osea en el head, el último link, que debo de hacer?

Comment: el ./ no es necesario para las rutas de styles e imágenes (es suficiente con poner href="styles.css"), el código no debería darte problemas, podrías agregar una foto de como es la estructura de archivos? El arbol, quizás el archivo css no esté en el mismo nivel que el index..
También estoy viendo que el margen izquierdo 900% podría no ser una buena opción. Aunque se está comportando como 90%.

Comment: @SebastianSirrett Si quieres que tu stylesheet se aplique sobre los demas, debe ir ultimo.

Comment: Otras alternativas que podrías intentar para ver dónde está el error son: 1. Limpia la caché del navegador: A veces los archivos CSS se almacenan en caché en el navegador y pueden no reflejar los cambios más recientes. Utiliza la combinación de teclas "Ctrl + Shift + R" (o "Cmd + Shift + R" en Mac) para forzar una recarga del archivo CSS. 2. Verifica los errores en la consola del navegador: Abre la consola del navegador y verifica si hay algún error relacionado con la carga o el análisis del archivo CSS. Si hay algún error, corrígelo y vuelve a cargar la página. Si estás usando Chrome, puedes

Answer (score 0):

el src "./Img/GameSpot logo.png" esta mal, deberia ser "./Img/GameSpot/logo.png" si es que el logo esta dentro de la carpeta /GameSpot

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).